# Crash on StateMachineBuilder timer

Tags: java, spring, exception, state-machine

I use Spring `StateMachineBuilder` to create a Bean.

In the machine, I have an `Action` which repeats itself every second.

This is the minimal builder code to demonstrate:

```
@Bean
public StateMachine<State, Event> getStateMachine() throws Exception {
    Action action = s -> {};
    Builder<State, Event> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();

    builder.configureConfiguration()
            .withConfiguration()
            .autoStartup(true)
            .taskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor())
            .taskScheduler(new ConcurrentTaskScheduler());

    builder.configureStates()
            .withStates()
            .initial(State.STARTING)
            .state(State.ACTION, action, null)
            .end(State.DONE)
            .states(EnumSet.allOf(State.class));

    builder.configureTransitions()
            .withExternal()
            .source(State.STARTING).target(State.ACTION).event(Event.START)
            .and().withInternal()
            .source(State.ACTION)
            .action(action)
            .timer(1000)

            .and().withExternal()
            .source(State.ACTION).target(State.DONE).event(Event.STOP);

    return builder.build();
}
```

The bean can't be created, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.statemachine.trigger.TimerTrigger.doStart(TimerTrigger.java:51)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.LifecycleObjectSupport.start(LifecycleObjectSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.registerTriggerListener(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:415)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.<init>(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine.onInit(AbstractStateMachine.java:258)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.LifecycleObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(LifecycleObjectSupport.java:67)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.config.ObjectStateMachineFactory.buildStateMachineInternal(ObjectStateMachineFactory.java:79)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.config.AbstractStateMachineFactory.buildMachine(AbstractStateMachineFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.config.AbstractStateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(AbstractStateMachineFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineBuilder$Builder.build(StateMachineBuilder.java:128)
```

If I remove `withInternal() [...] .timer(1000)`, it works but I lose the repeat functionality.

*What is wrong with my builder code?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in spring statemachine.  This only happens if you are using the StateMachineBuilder instead of configuring your StateMachine with springboot.

In AbstractStateMachineFactory.java it does not set the taskScheduler on the TimerTrigger when it creates a new instance of it.  I was able to fix this by adding:

```
AbstractStateMachineFactory.java : 547

if( taskScheduler != null )
{
  t.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
}
```

I submitted a pull request to the project here [#178](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/pull/178).